# I uninstalled systemui... now phone stops working

Tags: system-apps

I have [this](http://www.yugatech.com/mobile/skk-announces-aura-edge-for-php1999) phone, it is rooted.

I backed up the systemui which total size is smaller than 5mb then I uninstalled it using titanium backup then a message appeared "unfortunately systemui has stopped working" so I tried to restore it with TB but takes too much time (waited 20 minutes but still restoring).

I restarted the phone then the message still shows and its a black screen in the background... I tap "ok" and the message disappear a few moments but shows again and again.

Then I did a factory reset but the message "unfortunately systemui has stopped working" still showing with a black screen in the background.

How will bring back this systemui? is it possible with adb?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have root and ADB access, which I assume you do.

1. Connect phone to PC. Verify ADB access by executing `adb devices` in command prompt - it should show your device under "list of attached devices".
2. From there, do `adb push /PATH/OF/BACKUP/SYSTEMUI/ON/PC /sdcard` to push SystemUI to internal storage.
3. Execute `adb shell` and then `su` to get a root shell.
4. Execute `mount -o remount,rw /system` to remount `/system` for read-write access.
5. Execute `cp /sdcard/SystemUI.apk /PATH/OF/SYSTEMUI` where `/PATH/OF/SYSTEMUI` is where your SystemUI should be. For many recent devices it should be `/system/priv-app/SystemUI`.
6. Execute `chmod 0644 /PATH/OF/SYSTEMUI/SystemUI.apk`.
7. Reboot phone.

Do report back if you're successful or if any error pops up - do not attempt to proceed without knowing the error for sure. If you don't know how to use ADB or how to extract APK from a TiBu backup, search engines are your best friend.